# monit is not able to read mongod.lock

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, monit

I am writing a [monit](https://mmonit.com) script for mongo(in ubuntu). Script given below

```
check process mongodb
  with pidfile "/var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock"
  start program = "/sbin/start mongodb"
  stop program = "/sbin/stop mongodb"
```

But I am getting error log

```
monit: Error reading pid from file '/var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock'
```

Please let me know if any work around in monit for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Monit needs a pid file (containing the pid of the mongod process) so you have to create it when you start mongod

```
#!/bin/bash
mongod &
echo "$!" > /var/run/mongod.pid
```

and set /var/run/mongod.pid as pidfile

Comment: Thanks for the response. To add to this,I found another way to create pid file while starting mongo service by having the pid file location in mongo config file(/etc/mongod.conf) itself. Just add pid file location like this pidfilepath=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I found the pid file here: `/var/run/mongodb.pid`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using MongoDB, this solved my problem:
`chown -R mongod:mongod /var/lib/mongodb`